# newbie: Python print() generate different output on different compiler

Tags: python

i´m pretty new to python and while playing around with browser, Visual Code and Sypder, i have discovered different results. i have searched in the internet, but found nothing helpfull-maybe i´m using the wrong keywords.  Here´s my Code:

```
a=1
print(a,'+',a,'=',a+a)
```

web Output (same as tutorial):

**1+1=2**

Spyder/VisualCode:

**(1,'+',1,'=',2)**

Why is that? And how can i "fix" it, e.g. in Sypder?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: what version of python are You using? in VS Code

Comment: Works fine for me on Python 3.8.6.

Comment: I suppose You have a 2.7 or other 2.x version of python which is first of all deprecated and unless You need it for something specific I suggest You uninstall it and install a newer version of python (prefferably 3.6 or higher (because of `f strings`)) like 3.8 or 3.9 or sth like that

Comment: Thank you all! There were three Versions of Python. 2.7 (Anaconda), 3.7 32bit and 3.6 64bit. After uninstalling 2.7 i was asked which one to use now. That question didn´t appear when installing a few days ago... Now everything works fine! Thanks again.

Comment: @Matiiss don't uninstall it, necessarily. This can mess up the OS if it is the system python on various linux distros, or macOS